# Как сэмулировать потерю и возврат фокуса?

Tags: autocomplete, jquery, php, javascript

Собственно надо соорудить костыль или каким-то образом решить трабл. Есть код:

```
function ac_catch(el) {
    q = $("#" + el.id).val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "ac.php",
        data: 'q=' + q + '&' + 'id=' + el.id,
        success: function (html) {
            ac_data = html;
            $("#" + el.id).autocompleteArray(String(ac_data).split("\n"), {
                delay: 10,
                minChars: 1,
                matchSubset: 1,
                autoFill: false,
                maxItemsToShow: 15
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Автокомплит используется по множеству инпутов, и срабатывает только после смены фокуса на другой и повторного возвращения обратно. Можно ли как-нибудь сэмулировать потерю и возврат фокуса, но так чтобы фокус перекидывался не на инпут(ну крайний вариант я сделаю hidden, хотя не знаю будет работать на нем ивент), либо подскажите, где я дурак.)

**UPD**

И вообще кто-нибудь сталкивался с реализацией разного автокомплита на множество инпутов - можете подсказать рабочий вариант?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery("#needs_to_be_active").focus() - передаст фокус элементу с id=needs_to_be_active.

Следовательно, фокус, который был на предыдущем элементе, уже на нём не будет - кэп.

А вообще НЕ юзайте этот код для реализации autocomplete!!! Если вам нужно производить такие "махинации", то невольно должен появится вопрос: "Всё ли я правильно делаю?".

[Вот](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/AutoComplete/AutoComplete.aspx) пример AutoComplete как он сделан в AjaxToolkit. Учитесь, пользуйтесь, радуйтесь! (ASP.NET)

[Вот](http://www.linkexchanger.su/2008/39.html) ещё пример AutoComplete . (PHP)

Comment: Дело как раз в том, что уже перерыл море инфы по этому вопросу и постоянно натыкался на какой-нибудь гемор, со второй ссылкой я знаком, для одного поля нет проблем, а вот когда появляется второе поле, результаты автокомплита смешиваются((. Очистка кэша, почему-то приводит к неработоспособности скрипта в целом. Поэтому я и перешел на способ хранить кэш самому.

Comment: Первое, что приходит в голову - создать ещё autocomplete2.php, которая будет обрабатывать второй автокомплит. <br /><br />
А лучше всего к autocomplete.php добавить ключ типа:<br /><br />
autocomplete.php?autoNum=1 (для первого автокомплита)<br />
autocomplete.php?autoNum=2 (для второго автокомплита)

Comment: Да, собственно, с разделением проблем не возникает , я отправляю 'id=' + el.id и ac.php в зависимости от id и текущей выбранной таблицы высылает разные варианты автокомплита.

Answer (score 0):

Решил проблему путем использования библиотеки Jquery UI Autocomplete. Походу она оказалось менее глючная.

```
$( "#"+el.id ).autocomplete({source: String(ac_data).split("n")});
```